# XML declaration not playing nice with PHP

Tags: php, xml, quotes

I'm using PHP to output custom XML based upon values stored in a MySQL database. I have the following at the start of the condition:

```
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
```

(I've also tried this variation:

```
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
```

to no avail.)

However, this is always outputted (in every browser and even when viewed as a downloaded file from `wget`) as:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8 ?>
```

Somewhere along the line, the single quotes around the version number and encoding got dropped. Where did I go wrong and what can I do to fix this? I'm getting errors from my parser and I believe it's because this declaration is not following the XML standard of having either single or double quotes around these values.

Comment: That's really bizarre that PHP would drop quotes, but even so you should use double quotes isntead of single quotes for xml docs.

Comment: Hmph. Still the same result but I guess you're right in utilizing double quotes.

Comment: Sounds to me like some output post-processing is taking place. I have no experience with it, but perhaps something like `tidy.clean_output = On` in your `ini` settings? Seems unlikely `Tidy` would remove quotes in stead of add them, but who knows. Perhaps some similar post-processing tool is configured on your server's setup. (Be it PHP post-processing, of post-processing done by your webserver).

Comment: I'm on a shared hosting account, my options are limited as to `ini` settings... I just tried `ini_set("tidy.clean_output", "No");` with the same result.

Comment: Add `exit;` right after the `echo` and see the result. Do you have output buffer and did some post processing in the buffer?

Comment: Maybe try `echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";`?

Comment: @f1ames: Already tried that, but killneel just got it with his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because the content type of your document is already set to text/html (by default by php).

The solution to this is to set this as a header rather than echo it.

eg :

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
```

to set the charset :

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

And make sure that you set this BEFORE you output (echo) anything else.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That totally would not explain the automatic removal of quotes.